How to change the keyboard layout so that the keys marks match what is actually written
Ubuntu 24.04.1 has been installed on a Japanese laptop having a Japanese keyboard.
Initially the keyboard layout selected during install was "US keyboard".
How to change the keyboard layout to "Japanese" so that hitting a key does input what's marked on the key.
For instance Shift 8 on a Japanese keyboard is ( but on a US keyboard it's *.
It seems that the settings have changed on 24.04, and I can't see where one can change the keyboard layout.

Could do it.
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

Choose the Generic 105 (depending on your physical keyboard) then Japanese.
On 2024.04, the mozc configuration is in a ibus_config.textproto file. To be sure I changed all these files (2).
As root
# vi `find / -name ibus_config.textproto`

Change
 layout : "default"

To
 layout : "jp"

